# MVVM: close auth window and open another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

guys. What i need to do if i want auth user, close auth- window and open new window which will contain some information?

```
<Window x:Class="VSgonnadie.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:nspase="clr-namespace:VSgonnadie"
    Title="Auth" Height="236.564" Width="166.922">
<Window.DataContext>
    <nspase:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,1">
    <Button x:Name="AuthButton" Content="Авторизация" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,152,0,0" Command="{Binding Log}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="34" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="19,63,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Login}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="19,111,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Password}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label Content="Please, log- in" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="4.176,4.97" Margin="19,19,0,0" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

</Grid>
```

I'm trying to do that by passsing window name to RelayCommand, but it's not working

```
public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public string Login {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Password { 
        get; 
        set;
    }
    public ViewModel(){
        Login = "Login";
        Password = "Password";
    }

    private ICommand login;
    public ICommand Log
    {
        get{
            //here i'm thinking i'll get current window in 'win' param
            return login ?? (login = new RelayCommand<Window>((win)=>{
            }));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'it's not working' mean, exactly?

Comment: I'm getting RelayCommand lambda win is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding your `CommandParameter` to `ElementName=MainWindow`.  You don't have an element with that name in scope (from what you've shown, at least).  You should be seeing binding error logged in the Output window.

Add `x:Name="MainWindow"` to your `Window` declaration.

```
<Window x:Class="VSgonnadie.MainWindow" x:Name="MainWindow" ...
```